# How to delete from shared drive without confimation?

Tags: macos, nas

Is there a way to delete files/folders from a shared drive, i.e. a NAS drive, without the confirmation dialog popping up?

[image]

Comment: If you press Command-Option-Delete, however, the networked file will be deleted immediately, without any warning at all. As with the normal method of deleting a networked file, this deletes the file immediately.

Comment: @Udhy Hmm, doesn't work for me. On High Sierra or Catalina. Command-Option-Delete does nothing, Command-Option-Backspace again brings up the dialog..

Comment: did you try command-backspace only? It will at least delete files and put it in Trash without any popup.

Comment: @Udhy command-backspace brings up the confirmation dialog too, if deleting from NAS.